# Kafka cluster timeout after 60 seconds without any message in topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a problem with kafka cluster installed on k8s. When consumer is connected to the given topic and there are no messages in that topic for about 60 seconds, the connection is aborted. The problem is only on the cluster (when i am using kafka on local computer with the same configuration than it works fine). Kafka is installed from bitnami helm chart. I tried to set different properties like session timeout, but it doesn't work. Thanks for help

Kafka consumer properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group-id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1000
spring.kafka.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.use.type.headers=false
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=java.lang.String
```

Comment: Can you share your Kafka consumer config and the code used for consume messages?

Comment: Yeah, sure, configuration is in the post below

Comment: Try to compare local broker with k8s configurations, pay attention at `group.min.session.timeout.ms` and `group.max.session.timeout.ms` properties.

Comment: there are default values (6s and 30s) in both server.properties

Comment: 1) `kafka` isn't a complete k8s DNS service name. Have you tried the full address including the domain and namespace? Can you share the description of the service you're trying to connect to? 2) What log output do you get from spring?